# FFMPEG Doodstream compression method

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, frame-rate

I was wondering if its possible to know the convert process of Doodstream, this is the subject, I have Harry Potter Movie at 60FPS, it's about 4.6 -4.7 GB 1280 resolution. I uploaded to Doodstream and after the website processed the video its size is 1.3 GB. Wondering why that size I first played the video and for my surprise it's definitely at 60fps or more than 30 at least. So I downloaded it and with the FFPROBE it shows that it's 30 FPS. I'm wondering what kind of compression could have done the Doodstream.

Here are the videos if you are interested seeing the FPS:

60FPS: https://evoload.io/v/6DjHSdp6p3hkzr

Processed in Doostream: https://evoload.io/v/7GPP4oINkimXF2

PD: I already uploaded both into Evoload, could use the Doodstream link for the processed one but I had the Evoload interface opened. Didn't upload the 60FPS version to Doodstream because the obvius, it would be converted.

Here are the FFPROBE logs

60FPS:

> ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg
> developers   built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
> configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2
> --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared   libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100   libavcodec     57.107.100 /
> 57.107.100   libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100   libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100   libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100   libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0   libswscale      4.  8.100 /
> 4.  8.100   libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100   libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/content/drive/MyDrive/HP-60.mp4':   Metadata:
> major_brand     : isom
> minor_version   : 512
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
> encoder         : Lavf57.83.100   Duration: 02:38:50.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4112 kb/s
> Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1276x532 [SAR 97:103 DAR 30943:13699], 3853
> kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 19001 tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
> Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 243 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : SoundHandler

Doodstream processed log:

> ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg
> developers   built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
> configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2
> --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared   libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100   libavcodec     57.107.100 /
> 57.107.100   libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100   libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100   libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100   libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0   libswscale      4.  8.100 /
> 4.  8.100   libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100   libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/content/drive/MyDrive/HP-DOODSTREAM.mp4':   Metadata:
> major_brand     : isom
> minor_version   : 512
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
> encoder         : Lavf58.76.100   Duration: 02:37:12.43, start: -0.020227, bitrate: 1254 kb/s
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1276x532 [SAR 97:103 DAR 30943:13699], 1118 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr,
> 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : SoundHandler

Answer (score 1):

The resulting video is very blurry and lossy. It's quite possible that when you provide a 60fps stream, it would blend 2 frames into one to create 30fps output. This would look like a very fluent video, especially at relatively low resolutions like 720p.
With the amount of blur and lossy encoding, it's perfectly possible that this file is 'only' 1.3GB.
Regardless, the compression is h264@1.1mbit/s with aac@128kbit/s.

Since you're new, perhaps a little word of advice: be very careful when posting copyrighted content, especially a full feature length film.

Comment: Thanks, for the explaining and the advice, I already deleted the videos since my doubt was answered from you. By the way, in that case, what the FFMPEG comand would be? Example, let's say I have a 30fps video that I want that kind of result, or do I need to convert it to 60fps first? Thanks.

Comment: @inmercamacaro you can show thanks by upvoting the Answer as useful.

Comment: @MartijnBrouwer _"It's quite possible that when you provide a 60fps stream, it would blend 2 frames into one to create 30fps output"_ Your intuition is on the right path. Look near bottom of those FFmpeg outputs. The codec (**tbc**) is H264 and container (**tbn**) is MP4. Anyways.. Notice that `119.88 tbc`?? So it's set to 120 fps but Asker sees it play (**tbr**) at 60 fps suggesting the video was interlaced (two frames/fields per image). I think conversion blended 2 as 1 frame so new output is still 60fps (and visually same to human eyes).

Comment: **PS:** The confusing part is when the 2nd output has **tbc** of 60 fps but plays **tbr** of 30 fps. At this point it might not be the numbers in the file but whatever the media player chooses to read or calculate (from **tbn** + total frames) as the actual FPS. I would check myself but I have no heart to download a gig's worth of video just to check a frame rate number.

Comment: Let me see if I can trim a portion and post the link, what you say it's interesting, I'm searching more about it.